# Remove Duplicates from Array of Objects (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord, autocode

*without `_.uniq`, as it doesn't work on my platform ([autocode](https://autocode.com))*

I tried filtering using `==`, but it didn't work.
I also tried `_.uniq`, which didn't work either.

Code:

```js
      var tags = [...new Set(bot.tags)]

      for (var i = 0; i < bot.tags.length; i++) {
        tags1 += `\`${tags[i].label}\` `;
        
        tags2.push({
          label: `${tags[i].label}`,
          value: `${tags[i].name}`,
          default: false,
        });
      }
      
      console.log(tags2);
```

Current value of `tags2`:

```js
[
  { label: 'Anime', value: 'anime', default: false },
  { label: 'Social', value: 'social', default: false },
  { label: 'Moderation', value: 'moderation', default: false },
  { label: 'Fun', value: 'fun', default: false },
  { label: 'Anti-scam', value: 'anti-scam', default: false },
  { label: 'anti-scam', value: 'anti-scam', default: false },
  {
    label: 'Multiple Languages',
    value: 'multiple-languages',
    default: false
  },
  { label: 'Minecraft', value: 'minecraft', default: false },
  { label: 'Fun', value: 'fun', default: false },
  { label: 'Moderation', value: 'moderation', default: false },
  { label: 'Logging', value: 'logging', default: false },
  { label: 'anti-nuke', value: 'anti-nuke', default: false },
  { label: 'Utility', value: 'utility', default: false },
  { label: 'Multi-language', value: '-multi-language', default: false },
  { label: 'Anime', value: 'anime', default: false },
  { label: 'Logging', value: 'logging', default: false },
  { label: 'Together', value: 'together', default: false },
  { label: 'Utility', value: 'utility', default: false },
  { label: 'anti raid', value: 'anti-raid', default: false },
  {
    label: 'DiscordTogether',
    value: 'discordtogether',
    default: false
  },
  { label: 'Social', value: 'social', default: false }
]
```

It seems that there are a few values with double `value`, although they have a different `label`. How can I fix that?

(I need to sort not by uniqueness of the whole object - only by it's `value`)

Comment: `I also tried _uniq_` what is that? `it doesn't work on my platform` - why not? perhaps you *did it wrong™*

Comment: `_.uniq`  is likely the lodash lib, have you got this installed?.  If not, pure JS it's pretty easy to duplicate.. eg..  `[...new Set(array)]`

Comment: can you post some code so we can assess what you have done so far?

Comment: @Bravo idk why, my platform has a unique way to use dependencies (`const ... = require('...');`), and I tried multiple times and it doesn't seem to work (although other NPM dependencies do.

Comment: @Keith I tried to install it -- it didn't work.

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro I have everything ready, I just need to find a way to filter it.

Comment: `my platform has a unique way to use dependencies` how is that unique? looks like every old school node.js code ever

Comment: @Bravo by unique I mean I don't use npm in the cmd.

Comment: again, there's nothing unique about that

Comment: @Bravo I didn't have another word -- or knowledge it was the same in other platforms. The way it is documented made it seem like it is unique to this platform. Anyway, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Well, I have a solution - I'm keeping the `value` in an array. May not be the fastest performance wise, but...

I can't post it tho, as StackOverflow decided I'm not good in asking questions.

Comment: @Daniel You can't post an answer because the question is closed (I've voted to reopen it). As commented in an existing answer using `Set` won't help. Using a case insensitive comparison between bot tag label properties (or comparing their valules) may what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using javaScript you can use **Set**

> A set is a collection of items which are unique i.e no element can be
> repeated.  Set in ES6 are ordered: elements of the set can be iterated
> in the insertion order. Set can store any types of values whether
> primitive or objects.

```java
// Use to remove duplicate elements from the array 

const numbers = [2,3,4,4,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,5,32,3,4,5]

//spreading numbers of the object into an array using the new operator
console.log([...new Set(numbers)]) 

// [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 32]
```

Comment: Thanks, Muhammad! I'll check it out.

Comment: It still doesn't work tho - there are still entrys with a double `value` (`tags[i].value`)

Comment: This  does not stop different bot tag objects with same valued `value` properties from creating separate entries in `tags`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on autocode and it's working.

```
var unique = tags2.filter((set => f => !set.has(f.value) && set.add(f.value))(new Set));

console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var unique = tags2.filter((set => f => !set.has(f.value) && set.add(f.value))(new Set));

console.log(unique);
```

1. `(set => f => !set.has(f.value) && set.add(f.value))` is a higher-order function that takes a `Set` (`set`) and returns a filtering function (`f => !set.has(f.value) && set.add(f.value)`).
2. `(new Set)` creates a new `Set` and immediately passes it as an argument to the higher-order function, creating a closure with the `Set` inside.
3. The returned filtering function is then used as the callback function for the `filter` method on the `tags2` array.
4. The filtering function checks if the `Set` (`set`) does not have the current element's value (`!set.has(f.value)`) and, if true, adds the value to the `Set` (`set.add(f.value)`). This ensures that only unique values are kept in the `Set`.
5. The `filter` method returns a new array (`unique`) containing only the elements that passed the filtering condition.